# Primefaces p:TabMenu - change background-color of active-tab

Tags: css, primefaces, tabs, background-color

I have a p:tabMenu and a css with my design. The problem is, that the background-color don't change when a Tab is active.
I have tried many things, but nothing works.

Here is my css:

```
.ui-widget-header,
.ui-tabmenu .ui-tabmenu-nav .ui-tabmenuitem a{
    background-color: #CEE0F6;
}

.ui-tabmenu .ui-tabmenu-nav .ui-tabmenuitem a:active,
.ui-tabmenu .ui-tabmenu-nav .ui-tabmenuitem a:hover,
.ui-tabmenu .ui-tabmenu-nav .ui-tabmenuitem a:link
{
    background-color: #A8C8EE;
}
```

The second part doesn't work.

Sorry for my bad English. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following CSS selector:

```
li.ui-tabmenuitem.ui-state-default.ui-state-active {
   background: #A8C8EE;
}
```

[image]

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't work for me, the tabs don't change there color, when they are active :(

Comment: You have to make sure that you got the right order of the css files, that way the inheritance would work correctly. if you go to the showcase website and add this css in the console you would see the difference right away.